# Can a generic type be infered from all the members of a tuple?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have the following issue, I want the get function to constrain the p parameter to the union of all the types of key2 in the array and at the same time the key3 should be keyof TFooKey.

```
type Foo<TFoo, TFooKey extends Record<string, any>> = {
    key1: TFooKey
    key2: TFoo
    key3: keyof TFooKey
}

// p should be union of all the types for key2 in the tuple
function get<TFoo, TFooKey extends Record<string, any>>(t: readonly Foo<TFoo, TFooKey>[], p: TFoo) {
    return t
}

// fails since TFoo is only infered from the first element
get(
[
    {
        key1: {
            key: ""
        },
        key2: "",
        key3: ""
    },
    {
        key1: {
            key: ""
        },
        key2: 0,
        key3: ""
    } 
] as const,
""
)

function get2<T extends readonly Foo<string | number, Record<string, any>>[]>(t: T, p: T[number]["key2"]) {
    return t
}

// Works but now key3 isnt necessarily keyof TFooKey
get2(
[
    {
        key1: {
            key: ""
        },
        key2: "",
        key3: "key"
    },
    {
        key1: {
            key: ""
        },
        key2: 0,
        key3: "anyKey"
    } 
] as const, 
0
)
```

Above are my attempts I commented on why they do not work, is this even possible ?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WyqpZW) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz thanks for pointing out that. I updated the question, anyKey is not a key of key1 yet there is no ts error. What you sent works prefectly thank you so much. Do you mind anwsering with the code so I can accept the anwser ?

Comment: I'll do so when I get a chance, but it might not be for ~24 hours or so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript's algorithm for inferring [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type arguments generally will not synthesize a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) from multiple competing candidate types.  When it need to match an array against `T[]` for generic `T`, something like `["foo", 123, true]` will fail to match, because `"foo"` suggests the candidate `string`, `123` suggests the candidate `number`, and `true` suggests the candidate `boolean`... and even though `string | number | boolean` would work for `T`, the compiler will not infer that for you.  It picks one of the candidates (the "first" highest-priority candidate) like `string` and then complains about `123` and `true`.

Often such a rejection is *desired*.  Most people think `declare function f<T>(x: T, y: T): void` should *reject* `f("abc", 123)`, but if `T` were inferred as `string | number` it would succeed.

Anyway it would be nice if the generic function author could tell the compiler that you would like unions to be inferred, and there is an open issue at [microsoft/TypeScript#44312](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44312) asking for that.  But right now it's not part of the language.

---

If you want inference to succeed you probably need to change it so that there's only one candidate for the type argument, and then do some type juggling to make the compiler validate the type inferred afterward.

So you'd need something like

```
declare function get<T extends ⋯>(
    t: T, u: ⋯
): void;
```

where whatever you pass in for `t` will be the inferred type for `T`, and then the [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) on `T` enforces whatever restriction you want.

Here's one approach:

```
declare function get<T extends { [N in keyof T]: VerifyFoo<T[N]> }>(
    t: T & readonly Foo<any, any>[],
    u: Extract<T, readonly Foo<any, any>[]>[number]['key2']
): void;
```

So we are restricting `T` to be some self-constrained type, `{[N in keyof T]: VerifyFoo<T[N]>}`, where presumably `VerifyFoo<X>` should extend `X` if and only if `X` is a valid `Foo<U, V>` for some `U, V>`.  And we also want it to be an array type, but I'm only enforcing this on the `t` input (where it's of type `T & readonly Foo<any, any>[]`).  And the `u` input should naturally be of type `T[number]['key2']`, but the compiler can't see that `T` will necessarily be an array type, so we use [the `Extract` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) to convince it.

So what is `VerifyFoo`?  Here's a possibility:

```
type VerifyFoo<T> = T extends {
    key1: infer V extends Record<string, any>, key2: infer U
} ? Foo<U, V> : never;
```

So we try to infer `V` and `U` from `T`, and then say that `VerifyFoo<T>` is `Foo<U, V>` if the inference succeeds, or `never` if it fails.  So if `T` has a bad `key3`, then `VerifyFoo<T>` will have a good `key3`, and these will not be compatible with each other.

---

Let's try it out:

```
get([
    { key1: { key: "" }, key2: "", key3: "key" },
    { key1: { key: "" }, key2: 0, key3: "keyd" }
] as const, 0); // error!
// Type '"keyd"' is not assignable to type '"key"'

get([
    { key1: { key: "" }, key2: "", key3: "key" },
    { key1: { key: "" }, key2: 0, key3: "key" }
] as const, 0); // okay
```

Looks good.  The compiler allows valid calls and rejects invalid ones.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAYgewQHgKoBoYDUZQB4hQB2AJgM4wBKUAxggE4nJkj0CWRA5pgIZFgA+ATAC8MAN4wA1lDABGAFzZMMsACYlGabIDMS1QgBm2GAF9goSLCxR2hsIhQAVYWKe4CxchOAw-2+SUOQ1sTfEJSCmo6RmZWDm4YPkEVWQ0YYNDUYFMYAH54JDRMLGElIigAN1sAbgtgQwBXIhoQNgQiGE4oEGR3cK8KSQBtADkMzoNjJwBdJRs7ByKnMZnhUwEACl9-ECV3ADIYeigeEg6AGzBClGTefgFhmfQdv0alAFECeh5WvswTmdLtdHMg7kkHk9HkRGgBbABGthmwwA5Ko1CiZsAAJQ+HLAbogTbDV4SAKKMmqJQAImpZlS6hp1IZehg1NUdNML38lNkFMkVLZnIZ6QADCyaaoSJzgDMkhQ6EQWJhRdiajAAPQa3D0egMACEwC1MCcVhgKPZsmlKIyFCICBA8rIbE4RB48IusBACBg4Gg5stYGpKIshOJpIFfKUkbATPpAXStIlbI59Ij5OjATjXITSnFAVZgZlcp4Co6ypgqvVxoQUh4YCAA)

Comment: Thank you for this, but I am struggling to understand `Extract<T, readonly Foo<any, any>[]>`, why this is needed and why `T & readonly Foo<any, any>[][number]['key2']` fails to produce the right type

Comment: Basically these are workarounds to deal with inference. There's no simple way to represent the constraint that also infers nicely. The compiler doesn't know `T` is an arraylike type (and constraining it to that wrecks the inference). So the compiler doesn't realize that `T[number]` exists. If you write `(T & readonly Foo<any, any>[])[number]` then you're going to get `Foo<any, any>` which isn't what you want, since `any` overpowers the type.  The point of `Extract<T, U>` here is that it will be seen as assignable to both `T` and `U` while evaluating to `T`. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes that makes it clear, thank you